# language are not changing in laravel localization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

How do I solve my problem ?
Let me tell that how can i change language in laravel web page

- List item

```
 Route::get('/{lang?}', function($lang = null){
     App::setLocale($lang); 
     return view('frontend.home');
    
 });
```

Comment: Do you have the corresponding translation files in your lang folder?

Answer (score 0):

This code will work only for the current request, so when you return the view, it's a new request.
So what you have to do is to persist the language, for each request, so we'll use middleware.
First of all, create a middleware, to check the which language is set, as follows,

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has("lang")) {
            App::setLocale(session()->get("lang"));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

What this code will do is, check if the session has the `lang_code` exists, so it will set it. 
After that, you need to add this middleware to your `$middlewareGroups`, inside  `app\Http\Kernel.php`, as follows :

```php
<?php 
'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class, # This is the line we will add

        ],
```

Then finally we'll tweak a little bit your function to become like this :

```php
 Route::get('/{lang?}', function($lang = null){
     App::setLocale($lang); 
     session()->put('lang', $lang);
     return view('frontend.home');
    
 });
```

Like this, within each request, the middleware will verify the language, and set it.